# Combining two DFAs into 1 DFA using concatenation

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

L= { w : w has exactly two a's and at least two b's}

[Picture of DFA's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mPHU.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mPHU.png

I have made the two DFA's separately, but I am having trouble combining them specifically the transition. I have attached the two DFA's. Can you help and explain it me please?

Thank you

Comment: Your first DFA accepts the language $L_1$ of words that have exactly two $a$s, and your second accepts the language $L_2$ of words that have at least two $b$s; your $L$ is $L=L_1\cap L_2$, the **intersection** of these languages. There’s a standard procedure for constructing a DFA for $L_1\cap L_2$ given DFAs for $L_1$ and $L_2$; are you familiar with it? The state set of the new DFA is the Cartesian product of the state sets of the DFAs for $L_1$ and $L_2$. Alternatively, it’s not actually too hard to design directly a DFA that accepts $L$ using the idea posted by **ml0105**.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Now that I think about it, I think the product machine for the intersection is the same DFA as I gave below! It is nice to have two interpretations for the same construction. Product machines are also a very powerful tool- I'm glad you mentioned them! :-)

Comment: Thank you both for your perspectives. I just don’t know how to make the intersection for them and I’m not really familiar with the procedure. I’m really confused of how to make the transitions. I need an explanation step by step for that please and what are product machines? Is a website or an app? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @ml0105 what is a product machine? Just asking is it a website and/or an app?

Comment: @KP1: We’re talking about a way to combine a DFA for a language $L_1$ and a DFA for a language $L_2$ to get a DFA for the language $L_1\cap L_2$. There’s a standard procedure for this; it’s described [this PDF](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2010/lectures/lect_04.pdf), among many other places online and in textbooks. You really don’t need it, however, to design a DFA for your $L$ using the suggestion in **ml0105**’s answer.

Comment: Let $M_{1} = (Q_{1}, \Sigma_{1}, \delta_{1}, q_{0}, F_{1})$ and $M_{2} = (Q_{2}, \Sigma_{2}, \delta_{2}, q_{0}^{\prime}, F_{2})$ be DFAs where the transition functions are total. A product machine is a DFA $M := (Q_{1} \times Q_{2}, \Sigma_{1} \times \Sigma_{2}, \delta_{1} \times \delta_{2}, (q_{0}, q_{0}^{\prime}), F)$, where $F \subseteq Q_{1} \times Q_{2}$. For a product machine computing the intersection, we take $F = F_{1} \times F_{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of Finite State Automata as memory-less algorithms. Effectively, each state corresponds to a Boolean flag. That is, arriving at a state indicates a true/false condition.

In using a programming analogy, it might be helpful to rename states using descriptive variable names. I might recommend the states:

- $q_{0}$: The initial state.
- $q_{a}$: We read one $a$ and no $b$'s.
- $q_{b}$: We read one $b$ and no $a$'a
- $q_{aa}$: We read two $a$'s and no $b$'s
- $q_{ab}$: We read one $a$ and one $b$.
- $q_{abb}$: We read one $a$ and at least two $b$'s
- $q_{aab}$: We read two $a$'s and one $b$.
- $q_{aabb}$: We read two $a$'s and at least two $b$'s
- $q_{\text{reject}}$: We have determined the input string is not in the language.

Hopefully the names of these states suggest natural transitions to consider.